# ASP MVC Ways to convert an element in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this list:

```
var slides = mContext.Slides.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.ID)).OrderBy(s => s.ID).ToList();
```

Now, in this list, there's an element which I'd like to change the type of.

```
public Nullable<double> TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

In the db, TimeStamp is a double in the OA format. This I'd like to convert to DateTime. My question is, where would it be best to do this? In the repository that gets the date? In the view using JavaScript?

If I'm doing it in the repository (which imo is the best option), is it possible to change the `Where()` expression to include a conversion of the TimeStamp type from double to DateTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option "In the repository with `Where`" looks like a bad idea because LINQ to SQL will not convert a custom method to the equivalent SQL.

"In the view using JavaScript" sounds very messy as you can do it upstream.

IMHO, the best way is to add an extra property in a partial class to make the convertion from OA to DateTime

```
partial class Slide 
{
     public DateTime TimeStampAsDateTime { 
       get { 

          return FromToDateTime(TimeStamp) ; // To be implemented
     }}  
}
```

Comment: Yep - partial class is the best solution - agreed.

Comment: Actually LINQ to SQL uses methods in your object model to represent user-defined functions. So, one option is to write and store your function on the SQL Server. There is a more complex solution this, which is described here: http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx/ but I would not use it in this scenario.